# I wrote a function for encrypting an input, but I am having trouble with a decryption function

Tags: python, encryption

My simple encryption function that works.

```py
def crypt():
    so = input("Enter secret number: ")
    old_dic = {chr(i): i - (int(so)) for i in range(ord("A"), ord("A") + 26)}
    inp = str(input("Cryptify: ")).upper()
    for key,value in old_dic.items():
        if len(inp) >= 1:
            bit = list(inp)
            spell = list(map(old_dic.get, bit))
            spell = spell[::-1]    
            print(spell)
            break
        else:
            print("Improper input.")
            break
```

running function:

> crypt()

> Enter secret number: 45

> Cryptify: Hello

output:

[34, 31, 31, 24, 27]

I would like to take this output list of numbers and print out what is spells using a decryption function and the secret number.

My decryption function that does not work.

```py
def decrypt():
    so1 = input("Enter secret number: ")
    new_dic = {chr(i): i - (int(so1)) for i in range(ord("a"), ord("a") + 26)}
    inp2 = list(map(str,(input("Decryptify: ").strip().split())))
    for key,value in new_dic.items():
        if len(inp2) >= 1:
            bit2 = list(inp2)
            spell2 = list(map(new_dic.get, bit2))
            spell2 = spell2[::-1]    
            print(spell2)
            break
        else:
            print("Improper input.")
            break
```

running function:

> decrypt()

> Enter secret number: 45

> Decryptify: 34, 31, 31, 24, 27

output:

[None, None, None, None, None]

I can not wrap my mind around what needs to happen, but my dictionary values are completely different between the two functions despite using the same inputs.

My desired output would be:

[H, E, L, L, O]

Comment: Your encryption function uses `ord('A')` but the decryption function uses `ord('a')`.

Comment: That's not the issue.  The encryption function turns capital letters into numbers.  Your decryption function is trying to turn lower case letters into numbers, but you're not giving it lower case letters.  I'll come up with something shortly.

Comment: Why are you looping over `old_dic.items()`? You never use `key` or `value`, and you break out of the loop on the first iteration.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You had several problems.  The big problem is that your decrypt function was trying to map lower case letters to numbers, but you aren't giving it lower case letters.  Essentiallyl, you need to reverse the key/value pair when you create new_dic.  Next, you are inputting ASCII digits, but never converting them to a number.

This code works.  See if you can spot the difference.  Oh, and don't use commas when you enter the data to descrypt.  Just separate with spaces, since you used `.split()`.

And, by the way, these functions are pretty much useless if they just print the answer.  You should return the answer and let the caller decide what to do with the results.

```
def crypt():
    so = input("Enter secret number: ")
    old_dic = {chr(i): i - (int(so)) for i in range(ord("A"), ord("A") + 26)}
    print(old_dic)
    inp = str(input("Cryptify: ")).upper()
    if len(inp) >= 1:
        bit = list(inp)
        spell = list(map(old_dic.get, bit))
        spell = spell[::-1]    
        return spell
    else:
        print("Improper input.")

def decrypt():
    so1 = input("Enter secret number: ")
    new_dic = {i - (int(so1)):chr(i) for i in range(ord("A"), ord("A") + 26)}
    print(new_dic)
    inp2 = list(map(int,(input("Decryptify: ").strip().split())))
    if len(inp2) >= 1:
        spell2 = list(map(new_dic.get, inp2))
        spell2 = spell2[::-1]    
        return spell2
    else:
        print("Improper input.")

print(crypt())
print(decrypt())
```

Output (I printed out the contents of the map dictionaries to help with debug):

```
C:\tmp>python x.py
Enter secret number: 45
{'A': 20, 'B': 21, 'C': 22, 'D': 23, 'E': 24, 'F': 25, 'G': 26, 'H': 27, 'I': 28, 'J': 29, 'K': 30, 'L': 31, 'M': 32, 'N': 33, 'O': 34, 'P': 35, 'Q': 36, 'R': 37, 'S': 38, 'T': 39, 'U': 40, 'V': 41, 'W': 42, 'X': 43, 'Y': 44, 'Z': 45}
Cryptify: hello
[34, 31, 31, 24, 27]
Enter secret number: 45
{20: 'A', 21: 'B', 22: 'C', 23: 'D', 24: 'E', 25: 'F', 26: 'G', 27: 'H', 28: 'I', 29: 'J', 30: 'K', 31: 'L', 32: 'M', 33: 'N', 34: 'O', 35: 'P', 36: 'Q', 37: 'R', 38: 'S', 39: 'T', 40: 'U', 41: 'V', 42: 'W', 43: 'X', 44: 'Y', 45: 'Z'}
Decryptify: 34 31 31 24 27
['H', 'E', 'L', 'L', 'O']

C:\tmp>
```

Comment: Thanks Tim. I see you changed up the new_dic variable quite a bit. This was very helpful. I actually didn't submit the full code in this write up. This is the "dummy" version so I could keep things simple and understand where I was going wrong.

Comment: Yes, your `new_dic` config was a big part of your problem.